# Convert serialized format

Tags: php, mysql, serialization

I want to know differences between
`a:4:{i:0;N;i:1;s:1:"0";i:2;s:1:"0";i:3;s:1:"0";}` and
`O:8:"stdClass":3:{s:1:"1";s:1:"0";s:1:"2";s:1:"0";s:1:"3";s:1:"0";}` serialize formats. How to write to get `O:8:"stdClass":3:{s:1:"1";s:1:"0";s:1:"2";s:1:"0";s:1:"3";s:1:"0";}`
 that format in php coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one is the **serialized form of an array** and the second one is of an **object**. Create an object and serialize it, you would get what you want.

Simple example would be -

```
$obj = (object) array('0','0','0');

var_dump(serialize($obj));
```

**Output**

```
string(55) "O:8:"stdClass":3:{i:0;s:1:"0";i:1;s:1:"0";i:2;s:1:"0";}"
```